# Display a field of one content type based on another selected value

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

[Screen Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290691/display-a-field-of-one-content-type-based-on-another-selected-value)

I am using **DRUPAL 7.** I have created  custom content types credit card detail. When adding a new card I want to select the country first and based on that loads related banks in the second drop down. I need help to resolve this issue.Thanks.

Note: country list is loading from countries module, where banks from a db table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use **[AJAX](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)**.

Using [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) you can add ID to the element which needs to be changed.

```
function MYMODULE_MYFORM_ID_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 //First add id to the field to be changed

  $form ['field_bank'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#prefix'] = '<div id="replace_textfield_div">';
  $form ['field_bank'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#suffix'] = '</div>';


//Then you can add AJAX to the countries field like this:

$form ['field_country'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_callback',                  
  'wrapper' => array('replace_textfield_div')
          );
 }
```

Now in your [ajax callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_callback) function:

```
  function MYMODULE_ajax_callback(){
    $country = $form_state['values']['field_country'];

      if($country == 'US'){

             $options = array('Bank1'=>'Bank One', 'Bank2'=>'Bank Two');
           // and so on . You can Load Banks from DB_TABLE and place them here according to your need
             $form['field_bank']['#options'] = $options;   

       }
   //AND OTHERS according to your requirement

  return  $form['field_bank'];

   }
```

Please remember to rename the fields according to your forms and requirements.